# Symfony3 relation one to Many add collection not working

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have relations between User and Token. I want create new Token and add to collection on user. Token has been save but not user id.

```
AppBundle\UserEntity:
    type: entity
    table: null
    repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\UserEntityRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        username:
            type: string
            length: 255
            unique: true
        password:
            type: string
            length: 255
            nullable: true
        salt:
            type: string
            length: 255
            unique: true
        email:
            type: string
            length: '100'
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
    oneToMany:
      token:
        targetEntity: TokenEntity
        mappedBy: user
        fetch:  EAGER



AppBundle\TokenEntity:
    type: entity
    table: null
    repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\TokenEntityRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        value:
            type: string
            length: 255
            unique: true
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
    manyToOne:
      user:
        targetEntity: UserEntity
        inversedBy: token
        joinColumns:
          user_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
            nullable: false
```

Create new object :

```
$token = new TokenEntity()
$token->setValue('lorem'); //in token table is field user_id but I want that doctrine set this field auto 


$user = new UserEntity;
$user->setUsername('example');
$user->setPassword('password');
$user->addToken($token);
```

Doctrine throw exception : Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null
What's wrong? Why doctrine not set user_id field automatically?

Comment: How Doctrine can set `user_id` on `TokenEntity` if user not exist yet?

Comment: If User object was created before than token entity also not work

Answer (score 0):

Your token is the **owning side** of the relationship.  This means that, in the database, it contains the foreign key column (in this case, `user_id`).

The most basic fix is to replace `$user->addToken($token)` with `$token->setUser($user)`.

If you want to use the style in your example, you can do so by setting the user on the token inside your UserEntity::addToken() method:

```
public function addToken(TokenEntity $token)
{
    $token->setUser($this);    // <--- This is key
    $this->tokens->add($token);
}
```